# Нотификации в расширении Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-extension

Мне нужно было сделать небольшое расширения для получения состояния с сайта. Сам код готов, только не могу разобраться с нотификациями. Да, и расширение с bootstrap, если это важно.

Отличным вариантом было бы использовать HTML5 Notification, но он не работает внутри расширения. Точнее там нет объекта Notification.

Я нашёл другой вариант - использование модуля `PopupNotifications.jsm`. Но не могу протестировать примеры, приведённые в документации. Получаю ошибку

> gBrowser is not defined

Используется некая переменная, которая, пока я не понял где существует.

Пример я брал здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_popup_notifications

Конечно, можно использовать дополнительные расширения для использования нотификаций, но я не хочу вот этих самых зависимостей.

Можно ещё использовать и sdk, но только ради нотификаций переделывать код уже не хочется. Мне нужна самая простая реализация.

Вопрос: какой есть вариант для добавления нотификаций (желательно на примере), который потребует минимаотных изменений? Продолжить копать в сторону `PopupNotifications.jsm`? Или использовать `createInstanse` для интерфейса `nsIDOMDesktopNotification` (здесь загвоздка - я не нашёл имя класса, как обычно используется `'@mozilla.org/...'`)? Для `XMLHttpRequest` я нашёл и использую такой вариант.

Можете что-нибудь посоветовать?

Comment: Выдержка из документации мозиллы: "If gBrowser isn't defined your code is either not running in the scope of the browser window or running too early.". Так что надо смотреть в какой момент вы gBrowser пытаетесь использовать.

Comment: Да, я тоже читал это. Я пробовал вызывать его из JS, который подключался из XUL, подключаемый как overlay. Может перемудрил, но всё равно ничего не высвечивалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первым делом вам надо определиться, какой тип нотификаций вам подходит.

1) ["Popup/Doorhanger" notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_popup_notifications) (PopupNotifications.jsm) по определению отображаются в конкретном окне браузера в привязке к конкретной странице. Они используются в самом Firefox для отображения запросов типа "сохранить пароль?", "разрешить странице сделать то-то?".

Поэтому логично, что они требуют от вас ссылки на браузер (в определенной вкладке - tab) (`gBrowser.selectedBrowser`).

Как ее получить зависит от того, *какой* tab вы хотите найти.

- Если бы ваш код работал в контексте *overlay для browser.xul* (как описано в [туториале Building an Extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Building_an_Extension#Extending_the_Browser_with_XUL)), для него было бы определено понятие "текущего окна", в котором код выполняется. Тогда `gBrowser.selectedBrowser` был бы определен и указывал бы на выбранную вкладку в текущем окне.
- Если ваш код работает в окне, не являющимся browser.xul, или вообще не в рамках окна (компонент XPCOM или JSM), то нужна дополнительная информация, на основании чего искать вкладку. В простейшем случае, если вы сами вызываете код в JSM из кода в overlay для browser.xul, вы должны передать ссылку на браузер в ваш код. В более сложных случаях - если вы используете один из механизмов уведомлений - вам может быть доступен какой-то объект, по которому можно найти вкладку. Если нужна помощь с этим, задавайте отдельный вопрос.

2) [Глобальные ("toaster") notifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop-up_notification). Отображаются без привязки к окну или вкладке. Используются для оповещений типа "новая версия готова к установке".

Есть разные API для их отображения, в зависимости от контекста выполнения кода:

- [Web Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) - для страниц
- Модуль Addon SDK ["sdk/notifications"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/notifications) - для расширений Addon SDK.
- Для "old-style" расширений и кода в Firefox - [nsIAlertsService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIAlertsService)

Первые два API внутри используют `nsIAlertsService` ([1](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/90d9b7c391d3/dom/notification/Notification.cpp#l1344), [2](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/notifications.js)).

Собственно, в документации по nsIAlertsService приведены рабочие примеры, простейший:

```
var alertsService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/alerts-service;1"].
                      getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAlertsService);
try {
  alertsService.showAlertNotification("chrome://mozapps/skin/downloads/downloadIcon.png", 
                                      "Alert title", "Alert text goes here.", 
                                      false, "", null, "");
} catch (e) {
  // This can fail
}
```

Comment: В идеале мне нужна нотификация без привязки к окну, вкладке и пр. PopupNotifications.jsm я бы использовал, если не осталось бы других вариантов. Собственно из п.2 вариант Web Notifications API мне и нужен. На JS примерчик сделал, все работало, только при переносе в расширение меня ждал неприятный сюрприз.
По sdk/notifications, я уже говорил, что не хотелось бы переписывать расширение для sdk. Но этот вариант я уже тоже пробовал и он работал.
А вот с alert-service не пробовал. Я искал подобные варианты. Его и попробую вечером.
Спасибо за столь подробное описание.

Comment: А что можно сказать по этому - nsIDOMDesktopNotification? Это вроде интерфейс для Web Notifications API. Но ни одно примера с ним не нашёл.

Comment: Выделил минуточку, попробовал с alert-service - работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Судя по всему, `nsIDOMDesktopNotification` - ошметки торопящихся разработчиков мобильных проектов Mozilla. Если [поискать](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/search?string=nsIDOMDesktopNotification), видно, что это название файла, а не интерфейса, в файле определен недокументированный интерфейс `nsIAppNotificationService`, который реализован только в [b2g](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/b2g/components/AlertsService.js#56) (телефонная прошивка мозиллы).

Comment: Здесь [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIDOMDesktopNotification] написано, что это всё же интерфейс, но страница какая-то пустая.

The nsIDOMDesktopNotification interface implements the DOM notification interface. See that page for details.

Comment: Раньше был такой интерфейс, сейчас `notification` переписан на [WebIDL](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:Overview#WebIDL_Bindings), поэтому XPCOM-интерфейса больше не существует. Но даже когда он и существовал, я почти уверен, что вы бы не смогли его использовать извне страницы.